# How to get checkbox value and save it on database

Tags: magento2, database, savedata

I have added a custom checkbox in checkout page, and I have added a custom column to sales_order and sales_order_grid tables, now I want to get the value of my checkbox and save it in my custom columns on database, but i don't know how I can do this.

My files to create checkbox:

**vendor/module/view/frontend/web/template/invoiceCheckTemplate.html**

```
<div class="col-mp mp-12">
<input type="checkbox" name="invoiceCheck" value="1" data-bind="checked: invoiceCheck, attr: {id: 'invoiceCheck'}"/>
<label data-bind="attr: {for: 'place-order-invoiceCheck'}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Send invoice'"></span></label>
```

**vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/invoiceCheck.js**

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
],
function (ko, Component) {
    "use strict";

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'vendor_module/invoiceCheckTemplate.html'
        },
        invoiceCheck: true
    });
}
```

);

**vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- Modifying an existing step-->
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="invoiceCheck" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/invoiceCheck</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>

                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                 </argument>
             </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
 </body>
```

And this is the InstallSchema.php that I have used for my custom columns:

**vendor/module/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
        'invoice_check',
        [
            'type' => 'boolean',
            'comment' => 'Send Invoice',
            'source' => Boolean::class,
            'visible' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'nullable' => false
        ]
    );


    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
        'invoice_check',
        [
            'type' => 'boolean',
            'comment' => 'Send Invoice',
            'source' => Boolean::class,
            'visible' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'nullable' => false
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

I am pretty new like magento 2 developer so I am very grateful for any help. Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Edit:
I have added the follow code:

**vendor/module/etc/events.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="transfer_value_to_order"
                  instance="Module\Vendor\Observer\TransferValueToOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**vendor/module/Observer/TransferValueToOrder.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Vendor\Observer;

class TransferValueToOrder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $requestPayload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
        // extract the checkbox value from request payload into $checkboxValue
        $checkboxValue = $requestPayload["invoiceCheck"];

       
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $order->setInvoiceCheck($checkboxValue);
        return;
    }
    
}
```

Now, I have de this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: invoice_check in
> /var/www/html/app/code/Module/Vendor/Observer/TransferValueToOrder.php
> on line 16

So I can't get the value of checkbox with `$checkboxValue = $requestPayload["invoiceCheck"];`

I'm working with Magento 2.3.5, my custom checkbox is in first step to checkout (I'm working with 2 steps checkout).

Comment: pls show us the contents of $requestPayload, var_dump it or smth.

Comment: I've tried to do var_dump to $requestPayload but I can't see the result, I guess I'm doing It wrong, I don't know how to do this in the Observer, could you tell me how to do this? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: No need to be sorry. add var_dump($requestPayload); exit;. Before hitting the Place Order button open the network tab of developer tools. Here there should be a request called payment-information. in the response tab of this request you should see your var_dump result. 

A more elegant option is to use the debugger and copy the inside of $requestPayload from there.

Comment: It is not working, for the moment this project is paused, if I find the solution later I will publish it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an observer.

I'm assuming your using default one page checkout from Magento, but this might work with other checkouts as well.

Configure the Observer

```
<!-- your-module/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="some.observer.name"
                  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\TransferValueToOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now the Observer code

```
<!-- your-module/Observer -->
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;


class TransferValueToOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $requestPayload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
        // extract the checkbox value from request payload into $checkboxValue
       
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $order->setInvoiceCheck($checkboxValue);
        return;
    }
}
```

Due to the inner workings of Magento the value will be persisted in the database. `setInvoiceCheck()` will invoke `__set()` magic method which will add the passed value into the inner `data` property of the `Order`.

Everything in the inner `data` property which has a key consistent with a column name in `sales_order` table will be persisted in the database.

Now I'm assuming that an ajax request is made when you click the **Place Order** button(default **Magento**) and that is why the non-conventional way of extracting params from the request, normally you would inject the `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` object and call the `getParameters()` method to retrieve them.

Hope this helps, cheers!

EDIT:
Also you might want to take a look at the current standard for building/altering db tables https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

EDIT 2:
Once saved on sales_order it will propagate on sales_order_grid;

Comment: thank you for your answer but i can't do it works. I will edit my question with your code implemented.

Comment: I tried above code not working https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327443/magento2-not-able-to-get-checkbox-value-to-save-in-order-table